# How to export tabular data from html to excel without columns merged

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, export, merge

I have some data in rows and columns (thousands of entries) in html file which I want to export or copy/paste into an excel file. When I do that the three column data in excel file becomes two column (two of the columns merge).

Sample of the html data is here:

```
19550101 000000 057 
19550101 010000 060U 
19550101 020000 A
19550101 030000 A
19550101 040000 057 
19550101 050000 059 
19550101 060000 060
```

In Excel column 2 and 3 merge so the data becomes unusable. It is the column 3 which is most important for me. I would be thankful if anybody suggest me a way out of this trouble to get the the data in excel/csv format without being distorted.

Regards

Comment: Try saving the data you want to import into a text file, then use Excel to import the data from the file.  Copy/paste can sometimes have strange results.

Comment: You could always try text to columns as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with dangowans, you can try importing data into a text file, then choose "Data" -> "Get Data" -> "From File" -> "From Text/CSV" in Excel.

[image]

You can see the preview format：

[image]

Then choose load:

[image]

Comment: yes it worked, thanks to you both dangowan and Bella. The only difference in the procedure I want to mention is that when after export from text file data from three columns was merged into one column so insted of load data I opted for transform data option--split column and use then space as delimiter. It somehow worked and data split into three columns.  Thnaks and Regards

Comment: @AfzalAhmed, Thanks for your responding. Since you have solved this issue, could you mind mark it as answer or vote my reply? Your support is the motivation for my reply.

Comment: I have already voted for the post but since i am less than 15 reputations so my vote is recorded but does not show up publically, thanks again